# how to upload the image in folder in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I cannot add image to the folder, I don't know why. I have customer folder inside my root folder.Need help.

This is my controller function:

```
function add_new_successfully(){

$config['upload_path'] = site_url().'customer/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';

$this->load->library('upload',$config);
$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

$data['customer_name'] = $this->input->post('c_name');
$data['customer_email'] = $this->input->post('c_email');
$data['customer_pass'] = $this->input->post('c_pass');
$data['customer_country'] = $this->input->post('c_country');
$data['customer_city'] = $this->input->post('c_city');
$data['customer_contact'] = $this->input->post('c_contact');
$data['customer_address'] = $this->input->post('c_address');
$data['customer_image'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$this->common_model->insert('customers',$data);

$this->session->set_flashdata('page_added','<div class="n_ok"><p>Customer added</p></div>');

    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Upload path is NOT an URL value which you tried to set here. It is an absolute or relative path to the file system.

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'customer/';//FCPATH is constant for file system path to root directory or better said path to location next to index.php file
```

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#preferences).

Comment: my details are uploaded to the database but folder doesnot...i change $config['upload_path'] = site_url().'customer/'; to $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'customer/'; but same problem....@Tpjka

Comment: Change `upload_path` for one I suggested you and tell me is there any difference.

Comment: Feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (and upvote) if your problem is solved. It is good practice that increase answerer's will to help but also make the answer more reachable after search for those with similar issue. #SOreadytohelp

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['upload_path'] = './customer/';
```

but you need to have a folder called "customer" in the project.